# How do I find the the equation of a curve using either $y=k(x-a)(x-b)$ or $ y=k(x-a)^2+b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Suppose a curve has y axis coordinates as $(0,0)$ and x axis coordinates as $(15/2,0)$. How do I find the equation of the graph using either $y=k(x-a)(x-b)$ or $y=k(x-a)^2+b$.

I have used this formula, $y=k(x-a)(x-b)$ and at one point I get $k=0$ for which I failed to get any equation. I have no idea how to go further down(needless to say I just have started learning about curves). Anyways, the equation is $y=15x-2x^2$.

**EDIT:** I just figured, the two points where the curve meets the coordinate axes are $x=0$ and $x$=$ \frac{15}{2} $ so we have two factors here; $(x-0)(15-2x)$ so if we multiply the two factors we obtain the final equation. I would like to know what are the other ways to get equations.

Comment: y=k(a−b)2+b ?? Shouldn't there be some term of x?

Comment: Oh sorry. Thank you!

Comment: how can the x axis cordinate be (0,15/2) can you please clear out the question a little

Comment: My apologies, it should be (15/2,0)

Comment: It's ok man I hope you have an answer ! I dont need to work on it now :) If you stil face any issue comment here

Answer (score 1):

We will use $y=k(x-a)(x-b).$

Clearly $k\neq0,$ since otherwise will have $y=0$.

Then the point $(0,0)$ gives $0=k(0-a)(0-b)=kab$. So either $a=0$ or $b=0$ or both.

Suppose that $a=0$ (or similarly $b=0$), then we will have $y=kx(x-b)$ and then the point $\color{red}{(\frac{15}{2},0)}$ (and not $(0,\frac{15}{2})$ like above) gives $0=k\frac{15}{2}(\frac{15}{2}-b).$ Then since $k\neq0$ we must have $b=\frac{15}{2}.$

Thus we have $y=kx(x-\frac{15}{2})=\frac{kx}{2}(2x-15)$ for any $k\neq 0$. So choosing $k=-2$, we get $y=-x(2x-15)=15x-2x^2$ for example.

---

Note that since the roots of the quadratic are $x=0$ and $x=\frac{15}{2}$ then it is of the form $y=k(x-0)(x-\frac{15}{2})=\frac{kx}{2}(2x-15)$ for some $k\neq 0$.

Comment: I know you gave your best effort answering this question. But unfortunately, I'm sorry, I couldnt understand your answer quite frankly. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sure, which part don't you understand? We substituted the points $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{15}{2},0)$ into $y=k(x-a)(x-b)$ to find $a$ and $b$ (and $k$ can be any number different from $0$). This gave us a family of quadratics whose roots are at $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{15}{2},0)$ .

Comment: Do you mean $(x,y)=(3,-3)$ and $(x,y)=(0,-18)$?

Comment: Actually I was comparing this math with other maths that I have done so far. Suppose a curve has x coordinates of (3,-3) and y as (0,-18). So this is how I did -

y=k(x-a)(x-b)
-18=k(0-3)(0+3)
-18=-9k
x=2

y=k(x-a)(x-b)
  =2(x-3)(x=3)
  =2(x^2-9)
  =2x^2-18

now could you please explain me your answer in terms of this math?

Comment: What does 'x coordinates of (3,-3) and y as (0,-18)' mean? Do you mean the points $(x,y)=(3,0)$ and $(x,y)=(-3,-18)$?

Comment: (x,y)=(3,−3)  and (x,y)=(0,−18) -- the one you assumed earlier

Comment: You got $y=2x^2-18$, but substituting $x=3$ gives $y=2(3)^2-18=0$ and not $-3$ like the point $(x,y)=(3,-3)$.

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting or confused. I wish I could show you the graph thats how it would be easier for you to clear me on my confusions.

Comment: [This](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gfraynjj14) is the graph for the problem above, where $y=\frac{kx}{2}(2x-15)$. You can see that the roots are at $x=0$ and $x=\frac{15}{2}=7.5$ and for any values of $k$ different from $0$, the roots will always remain the same.

Comment: Appreciate it. The graph made my confusions go away.